# Best way to CSV output a vertical list in a horizontal list

Tags: python, list, csv

Python newbie here. I've used XPath to extract some data from a website which gives me a list in a list that looks like this:

`[['1','2','3'],['4','','6'],['7','8','9']]`

Currently, when I export this to CSV, each of the 'inner' lists is displayed in a single cell like:

*Cell A1* `['1', '2', '3']`) *Cell B1* `['4', '', '6']` *Cell C1* `['7', '8', '9']`

which means I would have to remove the unwanted brackets and quotes, Text-to-Columns and transpose to get what I want, which is this:

```
1,4,7
2,,8
3,6,9
```

What can I do/use to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zip`:

```
import csv
d = [['1','2','3'],['4','','6'],['7','8','9']]
with open('filename.csv', 'w') as f:
   write = csv.writer(f)
   write.writerows(list(zip(*d)))
```

Output:

```
1,4,7
2,,8
3,6,9
```

Comment: You can use `write.writerows(zip(*d))`, no need for `list(...)`.